# Error building gear s2 companion apps on android studio

Tags: android, tizen-wearable-sdk

I downloaded gear companion SDK (**Accessory SDK**). From sample projects when I 
created android project (**FileTransferSender**). And Run the project 
I got following errors.

Can anyone help?

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\govind.salvi\Downloads\AccessorySDK_v2.4.0\Samples\Accessory\Samples(Web)\FileTransfer\Sender(Android)_Receiver(Tizen)\Sender\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png into C:\Users\govind.salvi\Downloads\AccessorySDK_v2.4.0\Samples\Accessory\Samples(Web)\FileTransfer\Sender(Android)_Receiver(Tizen)\Sender\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png




Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\govind.salvi\Downloads\AccessorySDK_v2.4.0\Samples\Accessory\Samples(Web)\FileTransfer\Sender(Android)_Receiver(Tizen)\Sender\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png into C:\Users\govind.salvi\Downloads\AccessorySDK_v2.4.0\Samples\Accessory\Samples(Web)\FileTransfer\Sender(Android)_Receiver(Tizen)\Sender\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing the app you mentioned and it's working fine for me. So far I could understand, **Failed to crunch file** error occurs due to **Maximum File Path Length Limitation**(240 characters) of Windows OS.

I would like to suggest you to move your project to an upper directory.